# FHIR Search by Referencing Resources

Tags: hl7-fhir

Is there a way to search for a resource by its referencing resources?  For example, is the a way to find all Observations of code = X with Provenance by agent Y?

`GET [base]/Observation?code=X&???`

One could:

`GET [base]/Provenance?userid=Y&_include=Provenance:target:Observation`

but that prevents any kind of filtering on Observation (which may create a volume problem in the response!).  Also, I don't need the provenance resource - I just need to make sure that the Observations I'm using have a certain provenance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, to the best of my knowledge, there's no way to apply filters to multiple resources unless you're using _filter or using a custom OperationDefinition.

Comment: Chaining allows filtering by attributes across reference boundaries - the "reverse" nature of the Provenance target reference though is the barrier...

Comment: Chaining allows filtering the base resource based on relationships it has, but there's no way to apply filters to both the base resource *and* included resources, whether using _include or _revinclude

Comment: My use case only requires filtering the Observations - existence of a particular flavor of provenance is the criteria.  Just need "reverse reference" chaining!